# Is there any youtube data api for analytics if yes how to use it in my node js web application which is user for uploading videos to YouTube?

Tags: node.js, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-nodejs-client

My web application is used for education purpose, and im able to upload videos to youtube but now i want to use analytics api so where can i get that api and how do i use it in my nodejs application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are. Maybe this should help.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs